# When to use import in SVN?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

If I want to upload a file in my working directory, I just add the files and then commit the file to the server. However, can I use import to accomplish this? What's the difference between import and add/commit?

Answer (score 11):

An import saves you one step: `add` and `commit` become a single `import`. A regular commit allows you to review changes in your working copy before committing them to the repository.

You cannot import a file that is already under version control. Apart from that, there aren't other major differences I can think of.

Depending on your Subversion client, one procedure may be harder than the other. In any case, you normally use import to upload legacy or third-party code and regular commits to upload your work.

Answer (score 2):

To add to @Alvaro's answer, from [svn import](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.svn.c.import.html) documentation,

`svn import` creates parent directories that do not exist.

After importing data, the *original tree* is not under version control.

Comment: "the original tree" is the imported data on client?

Comment: The *original tree* are the files in your computer you point to in the `import` command. Since they remain untouched and they don't become a working copy you can do stuff like importing from a DVD.

Answer (score 1):

The import is made from non-versioned files/directories.

The commit updates changes in your repo based on you versioned file structure.

They have completely different uses. Look at http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch01s07.html for a typical scenario.